# Mac Mini will not restart, cannot install updates (OS X El Cap 10.11.6)

Tags: macos, mac-mini

Something is preventing my Mac Mini (Mid 2011, core i5) from restarting. As as result, I cannot install updates. How can I find what is preventing the Mac from restarting?

If I have to restart to clear out the RAM or similar, what I have been doing is running the terminal command `sudo reboot now` but I cannot install updates this way. Thank you.

Comment: Will it shutdown?  (`sudo shutdown`)   If it can shutdown,  then you can power it back up which will be, in effect a reboot.

Comment: It will not shutdown via the Apple menu either, no.

Comment: ...all terminal commands work, but they don't allow me to install updates.

Comment: Have a look at this article:  http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/fix-mac-that-wont-shut-down-3597343/

Comment: Thank you, but I tried everything listed in the article already. How can I find what program is causing the issue?

Comment: Open up "Force Quit" by pressing `Command - Option - Esc`  Take note of what's running and kill everything you see there.

Comment: If force quitting as per Allan's comment doesn't resolve your problem, I would manually close all apps and then do a force shutdown by holding the power button down until the Mac mini powers off. Then, I'd restart the Mac mini in Safe Mode (by holding down the `shift` key immediately after powering up) and waiting for it to boot up. Note this can take quite a while depending on your setup. Once in Safe Mode, test to see if you can restart normally. If so, when booted normally again, test to see if it'll then restart okay again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading the OS to High Sierra resolved this issue.